# HTTPS Traffic between EC2 instances over domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have 2 EC2 instances in 2 different private subnets, both sitting behind a load balancer.
I want to setup communication between the applications in both instances over the domain name https url.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a [Route 53 hosted zone](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/AboutHZWorkingWith.html), add the domain to the hosted zone and have it [point to the load balancer via an ALIAS record](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-elb-load-balancer.html) to the Load balancer DNS record

Comment: Does this require setting Up a NAT gateway to route the traffic? or the traffic does not go through the public internet and stays within the aws network? And the load balancer should be internet facing to route it with route 53 right?

Comment: you don't need NAT gateways, the ingress is via Route 53 routed to the internal ELB and and should be within the AWS network.

Comment: Should it be an internal ALB or an external ALB? I'm using a public facing ALB in my case

Comment: let me do some checks, it should be external as an internal ELB will not be resolvable.